# Attribute value uses wrong case character Error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, attributes, case-sensitive

I'm getting the following error in Eclipse juno:

Attribute value (POST) uses wrong case character

in the following line inside one of my HTML files:

```
<form action="http://allteamz.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post"
    method="POST" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form">
```

Is there a way to tell eclipse to "ignore" this error? Tried a few things but nothing seems to be working..

Answer (score 11):

Go to Windows>>Preferences>>Web>>HTML Files>>Validation. A list should be shown and there should exist a title in bold called "Attributes". Selecting "Ignore" for the option  "Attribute value using wrong case character" should solve it.

Comment: Good answer. These errors were a pain in my butt. This fix also works for JSP files in the Spring Tool Suite (which is of course built on Eclipse).

Answer (score 4):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) the allowed values for the `method` attribute in a form element are only 'get' and 'post', lower case, so I think a better solution is change to lower case. This is strange to me because everywhere else these methods seem to be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse was acting funky but after the restart the normal validation-ignore worked.

Go to Eclipse (or Window) -> Preferences -> Validation -> HTML Syntax Validator, and then 'uncheck' both manual and build

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignoring the issue through Eclipse configuration try to use proper tag .
This error comes if something like this written 
< div **onClick**="..." > < /div>

Here one need to write **onclick**="" ; C in lower case .